# Clearing cache removed all styling

Tags: caching

I'm fairly new to Drupal, but when trying to install a new module, I was instructed to clear the cache. Now, all of the styling on my website is missing and I don't know what to do.

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: A custom theme based HTML5 starter kit for Omega, @NickyTheWrench

Comment: There are many possible reasons why this can be happening - we must narrow it down. View the source of the webpage or inspect it with firebug. Check to see whether or not there are any CSS files being successfully loaded within the HEAD element. Did you recently setup SSL for the website? Also check yourtheme.info file located in root/sites/all/themes/yourtheme - check that the stylesheets are listed correctly there.

Comment: If I inspect element on the homepage of my site, I can find several resources that fail to load. These are all located in /sites/default/files/advagg_css and /sites/default/files/advagg_js. The error says that I am forbidden to access these files, but they _do_ exist on the server.

Comment: Any luck with my answer below?

Comment: So did it fix it or not?

Comment: No, it didn't @kwoxer

Answer (score 0):

The webserver must not have the correct permissions to access those CSS and JS files. You need to set the correct permissions on the /sites/default/files/css and /sites/default/files/js directories. Allow read access at the very least.

Comment: I ran `chmod -R 755 .` in each of the directories but to no avail.